# Declaring variables in PHP query with sub query not working. Undefined index: deviceName

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some issues declaring a value in my php statement. The 2 values outside of the sub query declare fine but the one inside the sub query does not work and gives me Undefined index: deviceName.

```
    $sql4 = "SELECT endPort, startPort, 
        ( 
            SELECT deviceName
            FROM devices
            WHERE devices.deviceID = patching.endDeviceID
        )
    FROM patching
    WHERE deviceID =  '$deviceID'
    LIMIT 0 , 10"; 

    $query4 = mysql_query($sql4);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query4))
        {
            $startp = $row['startPort'];
            $endp = $row['endPort'];
            $endname= $row['deviceName'];

            echo '<tr class="logm"><td>'.$startp.'</td><td></td><td>'.$endname.'</td><td></td><td>'.$endp.'</td><td></td></tr>';

        }
```

Is it possible to declare this value and am i doing it wrong or is there another way round this issue.

Comment: joins are far more efficient than sub-querries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give the subquery result a name:

```
SELECT endPort, startPort,
    ( 
        SELECT deviceName
        FROM devices
        WHERE devices.deviceID = patching.endDeviceID
    ) AS deviceName
FROM patching
WHERE deviceID = '$deviceID'
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Though you should be using joins, not subqueries:

```
SELECT endPort, startPort, deviceName
  FROM patching
  LEFT JOIN devices ON(devices.deviceID = patching.endDeviceID)
 WHERE patching.deviceID = '$deviceID'
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew it was something simple but after a lack of sleep I was really struggling. i understand what you're saying about using a join, but due to the information required it actually returns the wrong value.

Comment: Instead of using USING(deviceID) try ON(devices.deviceID = patching.endDeviceID). That should give you the correct value using the join.

Comment: @user346271: What's the difference? \[ **edit** oh, one isn't `deviceID`.. oops! Good spot. \]

Comment: I changed the WHERE clause to WHERE patching.deviceID = '$deviceID' and it now works other wise it was ambiguous. That's partly my fault though due to the tables having a field with the same name.

Comment: @Shadoweski: And mine for not testing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a join for this:

```
SELECT endPort, startPort, deviceName
FROM patching
LEFT JOIN devices USING (deviceID)
WHERE deviceID = '$deviceID'
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

**Note**: If `$deviceID` is user input, you have to escape it with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: don't forget to escape `$deviceID` ;)